# php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo

Tags: php

```
copy() [function.copy]: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed:
```

When I use

```
copy("http://example.com/simple.jpg",$target);
```

that error occur.

Comment: Welcome to SO. The last (and most important) part of your error message is missing. You can edit your question to amend it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your server is unable to resolve the name `example.com` to an ip address, i.e. either the dns server is unreachable or there's a misconfiguration in your webserver's dns client.
How to resolve this issue depends on your operating system (and configuration).

Answer (score 0):

- copy will only work with URLs if fopen wrappers are active. Most likely they aren't on your system.
- Another probable source of problems might be the server you request that file from just doesn't exist or cannot be resolved via DNS.