# Copy file does not copy but gives error php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: -PHP

Tags: php

I am trying to copy an image from an url eg: `http://www.slate.com/content/dam/slate/articles/technology/technology/2013/01/130110_TECH_SamsungCES.jpg.CROP.rectangle3-large.jpg` which is accessible via the browser, but the error is: ***Warning: copy() [function.copy]: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known in***

```
$file_name="http://www.slate.com/content/dam/slate/articles/technology/technology/2013/01/130110_TECH_SamsungCES.jpg.CROP.rectangle3-large.jpg";

copy($file_name,"uploads/");
```

No error is returned when I use `move_uploaded_file($file_name,"uploads/");` and file is not copied too.

Any clue to what is wrong here?

Comment: The server that you're working from (and this may sound silly) - is it connected to the internet? Or is it an intranet environment that you have set up?

Comment: @adomnom it is connected to the internet.

Comment: @HamZaDzCyberDeV PHP 5.3.18 (cli) (built: Oct 18 2012 07:09:10)

Comment: @Jean If you have access to configure your server, try to enable **allow_url_fopen**

Comment: @HamZaDzCyberDeV it is open though.

Comment: @jean xD i get it, you have to specify a name ofcourse, try `copy($file_name,"uploads/test.jpg");`

Comment: I just tested this in my system and it works. (5.3.1).

Comment: @Jean I think this is a DNS issue, take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1945938/php-network-getaddresses-getaddrinfo?rq=1)

Comment: @HamZaDzCyberDeV Not DNS issue. User1765062 is using IP.  Probably something wrong with my pc.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$file_name="http://www.slate.com/content/dam/slate/articles/technology/technology/2013/01/130110_TECH_SamsungCES.jpg.CROP.rectangle3-large.jpg";

copy($file_name,"test.jpg");
?>
```

This works , make sure that:

1. You are specifying a destination filename for the copy command (not
   just a directory)
2. in your php.ini `allow_url_fopen = On`

Comment: It beats me why this error still pops up: failed to open stream: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known

Yes - allow_url_fopen = On

Answer (score 0):

It also works here, but try the next code, just changed the domain name to the resolved IP address:

Looks like the server is not resolving the domain correctly.

```
<?php

$file_name="http://50.17.234.211/content/dam/slate/articles/technology/technology/2013/01/130110_TECH_SamsungCES.jpg.CROP.rectangle3-large.jpg";

copy($file_name,  "uploads/130110_TECH_SamsungCES.jpg.CROP.rectangle3-large.jpg");

?>
```

Comment: Did you try that code? it shows the same error?

Comment: unfortunately yes.. :(

Comment: Does this help in anyway :Warning: copy() [<a href='function.copy'>function.copy</a>]: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known

Comment: The server IP changed to 184.73.229.231, try this one now or better try the next code to see if the server can resolve the domain name. I think the error has something to do with not resolving the domain correctly.
`<?php
$ip = gethostbyname('www.slate.com');

echo $ip;
?>`

Comment: It is something wrong with my system, I uploaded the files to the server and it works fine.  the php.ini file has allow_url_fopen=on, I wonder what is the problem.